# zsh: global alias to redirect to temporary file

Tags: alias, zsh

I want to add a global aliash in zsh which will look something like this:

```
alias -g t='> tmp-$(date +%Y%m%d-%h%m%s).txt'
```

What it should do is create a new timestamped temporary file in the current directory and redirect output to that file. However, the filename gets evaluated at the time of zsh being sourced instead of the alias being called.

I guess what I need is some sort of lazy evaluation. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Uh? No, the file name is evaluated each time the alias is used, so your code does exactly what you asked. You can test it for yourself. I can't think of any option that would make zsh work differently in this case. Unless you're using the alias in a function — aliases are expanded when the function is defined, not when it's executed.

Comment: Grr... this is what my expectatione was honestly. And, obviously, you are right. I was sourcing some modules after the aliases and they kept making tmp files every time a new shell was opened which seems to be a problem with what those modules are doing. Moving the aliases to the end of the rc file fixed this. Thanks a ton. What do you suggest I do with the question & answer now? Edit answer, delete answer, or delete question. Or leave it be?

Comment: Edit your question with [code that actually reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (with expected and actual output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out a way. More involved than I wanted it to be:

```
function redirect-to-tmp() {
  TMPFILE="./tmp-$(date +%y%m%d-%H%M%S)"
  cat >>! $TMPFILE
  echo "Redirected to $TMPFILE"
}

function redirect-to-tee() {
  TMPFILE="./tmp-$(date +%y%m%d-%H%M%S)"
  tee -a $TMPFILE
  echo "Redirected to $TMPFILE"
}

alias -g t='| redirect-to-tmp'
alias -g T='| redirect-to-tee'
```

Let me know if anyone else has a better answer.

Comment: those `while` loops aren't necessary here, better replace them with `cat >>! $TMPFILE` and `tee -a $TMPFILE`

Comment: Whoa! Why the hell did I not think of that. :D Thank you; that is so much neater.